# Implement accordion view for mobile break point grid for bootstrap and angularjs based application

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Angularjs and bootstrap for my application. I have multiple sections in my page and each sections has multiple columns. I have used bootstrap grid to show the list of items for tablet and desktops ranges and used "row" for each of my sections and then col- class. Due to default bootstrap grid css, it shows one column display at mobile breakpoints for each sections.

However we want only at mobile breakpoint it should display work as accordion control.

I don't want to use css to hide the markup for tablets and desktop and show mobile markup for accordion. I want to use same markup for all of my breakpoints.

I have gone through the bootstrap accordion control also angular-ui project accordion control, however both require new HTML markup.

How can I use same bootstrap grid based markup to show accordion control at mobile breakpoints. Please also note; I tried to use ":target" css properties however it doesn't seems working fine with angular.

Please also note; I am using single page application and HTML5(true) router.

Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking and found blog by Mary Lou which seems good solution to implement accordion using css only.

[Accordion using CSS Only](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/02/21/accordion-with-css3/)